# Determine if an arbitrary regex matches the whole string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a function that accepts a RegExp and a string, and needs to determine whether the RegExp matches the whole string, not just a substring.

```
function completeMatch(regex, str) {
   // ???
}
```

If I were writing the regex pattern, I could simply wrap it in `^...$`; however, someone else owns this pattern.

I suppose that I could turn the RegExp into a string, insert these characters, and then turn it back into a RegExp, but this seems messy:

```
function completeMatch(regex, str) {
   var patternStr = regex.toString();
   var slashIndex = patternStr.lastIndexOf("/");
   var newPattern = "^" + patternStr.substr(1, slashIndex-1) + "$";
   var flags = patternStr.substr(slashIndex+1);
   var newRegex = new RegExp(newPattern, flags);

   return newRegex.test(str);
}
```

Is there a cleaner way of solving this problem that doesn't resort to string manipulation?

Comment: `str.match('^'+regex+'$');`? By the way, just curious... what do you mean by "someone else owns this pattern"?

Comment: That should be `str.match(new RegExp('^'+regex+'$'))`. Please answer the above question.

Comment: @Alejendro Ivan @PHPglue - You're assuming `regex` is a string pattern, but the OP specifically says it's already a `RegExp`, so neither of these approaches will work. As far as I know, the only way to do this is make the RegExp a string, as you've suggested. That doesn't seem so messy to me...

Comment: For newPattern you can use `regex.source`, it removes the first and last `/` but for `flags` you have to do what you are doing (in ECMAScript 6 the answer is different)

Comment: @Alejandro Ivan By "someone else owns," I mean that the construction of the RegExp object is outside the scope of the function that I'm writing, so I can't *just* write the regular expression to meet my needs in the first place. @ tandrewnichols  This string-manipulation seems "messy" to me because I'm used to having separate "find" and "matches" methods on regex objects in different languages, and it seems odd that something approaching this functionality isn't build into the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "cleanest" way I can found is:

```
function completeMatch(regex, str) {
   var newPattern = "^" + regex.source + "$";
   var flags = regex.toString().split('/').reverse()[0];
   var newRegex = new RegExp(newPattern, flags);

   return newRegex.test(str);
}
```

But as you can see is pretty the same approach you are handling right now

Answer (score 1):

I've had this function which I use, here it is:

```
function fullMatch (regexp, string) {
    return (new RegExp('^'+regexp.source+'$', String(regexp).split('/').reverse()[0])).test(string);
}
```